# Is the HTML output of quill.root.innerHTML always safe?

Tags: javascript, security, xss, quill, websecurity

I want to save and load the rich text from a Quill editor. My plan is to call `JSON.stringify(quill.getContents())` and save the resulting JSON. Then to load and display the rich text I would do:

```
quill.setContents(JSON.parse(myJson));
myDiv.innerHTML = quill.root.innerHTML;
```

My question: is it the case that regardless of the contents of the `myJson` string, the above will only render the standard HTML tags which Quill supports? i.e. is it impossible to pick the myJson string in a way that the resulting HTML does something which couldn't have been accomplished by using the Quill editor UI in the intended way?

For example - if I have configured Quill to not allow images, I wouldn't want it to be possible to create a JSON string which would result in the above code rendering an image.